# Using left join syntax SQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have 3 tables:

```
**user**
idnumber | fullname
2015-01    sample doe

**Equipment**
id | Equipment
1     mic
2    Extension

**Reservation_list**
id | idnumber | reserve_slot | description | equip_id |
1    2015-011       1           sample         1
2    2015-011       2           sample2        2


**reservation slots**
id | reservation_int | reservation_out
 1     10:00               12:00
 2     1:00                2:00
```

I'm getting the idnumber here:

```
index.php?idnumber=?2015-011

$idnumber = $_GET['idnumber'];
```

How can be the result like this:(as you can see 2 tables join reservation_list and reservation_slots

```
reservation_int | reservation_out | description | equipment |
    10:00               12:00          sample      mic
     1:00                2:00          sample2    extension
```

as you can see it displays all the records of "2015-011".

Comment: ..don't forget to accept the solution !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT R1.description,
       R2.reservation_int,
       R2.reservation_out 
  FROM user AS u 
    INNER JOIN reservation_List AS R1 ON (u.idnumber = R1.idnumber) 
    INNER JOIN equipment as E ON(E.id = R1.equip_id)
    INNER JOIN reservation_slots AS R2  ON(R1.reserve_slot = R2.id) 
  WHERE u.idnumber = "2015-011"
```

Comment: its a 4 table now. it has equipment table please have a check ty.

Comment: @kimdecastro try now..!

Comment: @kimdecastro change the table names

Comment: thanks sir how can I echo the result? echo $row['R2.reservation_int']; ? using mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['fieldname'];
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104660/discussion-between-fr4ncx-and-kim-de-castro).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain that you need a `LEFT JOIN` here. A simple `INNER JOIN` will be more efficient and give you what you need:

```
SELECT
    RS.reservation_int,
    RS.reservation_out,
    RL.description
FROM
    user
    INNER JOIN Reservation_List RL ON user.idnumber = RL.idnumber
    INNER OUTER JOIN Reservation_Slots RS ON RL.ID = RS.ID
WHERE user.idnumber = '2015-011'
```

If you're requirements changed and you needed to list information about the `user` and any reservation type information, if it's available. Then you could switch to to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.